# Working from Outside EU while being Employed in Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card, working

I work for a German Company with a German Blue Card.

I plan to visit India for 3 months. Out of this 3 months 7 weeks would be Vacation. But the rest of the Time I will be Working from home.

So my question is, will this cause any issues related to Taxes and Insurance?

Any information regarding this situation will be helpful.

Comment: What does your employer say?